# x86-64 mul instruction does not multiply properly?

Tags: assembly, printf, x86-64, multiplication

I'm having weird problem with the `MUL` instruction on x86-64. It seems like the instruction does not properly multiply the 64 bit stuff in the register. I'm trying to make a simple code that just raises the 2 to a power defined by the caller (passed in `RDI`). The value in `RAX` seems to get stuck at a magical 28 limit for some reason. I'm probably again missing something very obvious here (probably misunderstood something about the instruction itself). Below is my code and output attached:

```
twotopwr:
    ;RDI contains the power
    CALL printfcall ;this prints the good value of 10 when testing with number 10 in RDI
    MOV RAX, 2;The 2 here
    PUSH RBX
    MOV RBX, 2;Multiplier
    CMP RDI, 0;If 0 then return 1
    JE ret1

loop:
    ;CALL printfcall
    DEC RDI ;Subtract the exponent
    CMP RDI, 0 ;Check if 0
    JE ret ;if 0 then return the value in rax
    MUL RBX ;Multiply rax by 2
    ;Print the rax content
    PUSH RDI
    MOV RDI, RAX
    CALL printfcall ;Debugging print
    POP RDI

    JMP loop ;Again
ret1:
    MOV RAX, 1;Exponent was 0
ret:
    POP RBX
    ;return value in rax
    RET
```

Outputs

```
The int is 10
The int is 4
The int is 26
The int is 28
The int is 28
The int is 28
The int is 28
The int is 28
The int is 28
The int is 28
```

My printing function:

```
printfcall:;Pass in RDI

        MOV RSI, RDI
        PUSH RDI
        MOV RDI, formatStrdec
        MOV AL, 0 
        CALL printf
        POP RDI
        RET
```

Comment: It looks like the only benefit you're getting from making `printfcall` a function instead of a macro is that it happens to align the stack by 16 sometimes, if you call it without having pushed anything first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `printf` will return the number of characters printed out in the `RAX` register which is 13 after printing this `The int is 4` first, that is why you get 26 in next iteration and that iteration `printf` returns 14 as written character number, which is 28 after multiplication by 2 and this is going on over and over again.

Comment: Also, do not use a `MUL` loop for powers of two. Just use a shift ;)

Comment: @Jester oh you are totally right, will implement this using left shift when I get this one to work first.